# whether it is possible to use a foreign key to the table enum?

Tags: mysql, enums

[image]

whether it is possible to use a foreign key to the table enum?
            CREATE TABLE `wiele` (
        `id_wiele` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `nazwa_wiele` CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id_wiele`),
        UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id_wiele`)
    )
    COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

```
    CREATE TABLE `gotowe` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `parametr` ENUM('Y','N','D') NOT NULL,
    `parametry` SET('A','B','C') NOT NULL,`enter code here`
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Foreign Key Mismatch Error :] .